# How to get Separate Data Item value from One Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello Friends i have one custom arraylist which include items like : `[t_id(PK) cat_id(FK), cat_name,total] .`

Suppose i enter five value on it like `({1,1,c1,100},{2,1,c1,200},{3,1,c1,300},{4,1,c2,400},{5,1,c2,500})`

NOw i want Total value of Category `"c1"` and `"c2"`

Means in output it should be like

```
"c1=600" and "c2=900".
```

So any idea how can i solve it

Comment: is it arraylist of a custom object?

Comment: @playmaker420 Custom Object

Comment: set getters and setters for the custom object. And iterate your arraylist. For(int i=0;i<arralyist.size();i++){text.settext(arraylist.get(i).getName()+arraylist.get(i).getId());} You can do something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how the bean was, here i tried something that may help you,

```
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(Custom custom : customList)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(custom.getCat_name()))
            {
                Integer i = map.get(custom.getCat_name());
                map.put(custom.getCat_name(), i+custom.getTotal());
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(custom.getCat_name(), custom.getTotal());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Map : "+map);
```

Output : `Map : {c1=600, c2=900}`

Answer (score 1):

It's guess but what I understood is like this

```
public class Custom
{
int t_id(PK);
int cat_id(FK);
String cat_name;
int total;

public Custom(int t_id(PK),int cat_id(FK),String cat_name,int total)
{
this.t_id(PK)=t_id; 
this.cat_id(FK)=cat_id(FK);
this.cat_name=cat_name;
this.total=total;
}
}

ArrayList<Custom> list=new ArrayList<Custom>;
```

Now if you want to get total no for `c1`

Do it like this.

```
int totalC1=0;
for(Custom c:list)
{
if(c.cat_name.equals("c1"))
{
totalC1+=c.total;
}
}
```